# Returning a list: Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Im trying to create a predicate that returns a list of all females. So far I have:

```
female(elisabeth).
female(queenmother).
female(diana).
female(anne).
female(beatrice).
female(sarah).
female(zara).
female(kate).

the_royal_females([X|_]).
the_royal_females([X|_]) :- female(X).
```

But this returns each female individuly like

```
X = elisabeth ;
X = queenmother ;
X = diana ;
```

How can i get it to return `[elisabeth,queenmother,diana]` instead?

Comment: @BhargavRao: This title change is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findall/3`:

```
the_royal_females(Lst):-findall(F,female(F),Lst).
```

`findall` puts in `Lst` all instantiations that `F` gets while satisfying `female(F)` in every possible way.

Comment: @false Why? I usually avoid `setof/3` because it returns false instead of `[]` when the goal cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Because `findall/3` shows the accidental order of solutions, whereas `setof/3` hides, them. And `setof/3` also works for more general queries etc. replace `female(F)` by `gender(F, female)`.  And then generalize the query replacing `female` by `Gender`. `findall/3` breaks, whereas `setof/3` remains correct.

Comment: I am aware of those differences, but I don't think they are relevant for this particular question. I do not think that `findall/3` breaks in that case, it just doesn't care about the free variables. So, when I have no other free variables involved and I don't care about sorting, I always use `findall/3` because it works when the goal doesn't succeed at all.